# Fabric release Xcode 6.3 codesign xcode-select

Tags: ios, xcode, release, ota, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to upload a release to Fabric & I'm getting errors as follows. I'm using the Xcode 6.3 (recently updated).

- Xcode: 6.3
- Fabric: 1.1.3
- OSX: 10.10.3

[image: An Error from Fabric tool]

1. What should I do to resolve above error & continue uploading the release via fabric desktop tool?
2. Is there any other way to upload binary to fabric?

Comment: XCode command line tools are already installed & I've just checked it using terminal & I found it working.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

1) To clear that error from Fabric.app: Quit Fabric.app, then run this command to clear the local cache:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac
```

You may also need to clear:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.run
```

Then restart Fabric.app and you'll be all set!

2) To distribute outside of Fabric.app, [use either method mentioned here.](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/beta-distribution/ios)

Comment: Hi Mike, I try to follow step one, but still same error is comming

Comment: hey @rajpara do you have the command line developer tools installed? Also, did you quit Fabric.app before clearing your cache?

Comment: @MikeB thanks for reply me back, I figure out problem, command line was installed but problem was I renamed xcode to xcode_3.6.2 so gcc was not able to run, 

I again rename it to xcode and its working fine now

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems that Xcode developer tools are broken because Homebrew isn't working either.

Comment: Ok, I solved it by changing path of `xcode-select`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30902106/1014048

Comment: Nice, works great! But i suggest to fix this issue for further versions ;)

Comment: same issue after upgrading to xcode 7.0. and solution #1 worked great

Comment: the same issue after upgrading to xcode 7.3, first solution still working perfect, thanks.

Comment: Just clearing the com.crashlytics.mac cache didn't work for me but also clearing com.crashlytics, com.crashlytics.data and com.crashlytics.run seemed to do the trick

Comment: Had the same issue with Xcode 9.1, followed Mike's instructions to fix it. Thanks Mike!

Comment: It works perfect now. ;) it is pretty awesome answer;) + 1000 and one bottle of wine for you...

Answer (score 10):

If you have multiple versions of Xcode installed on your system you may need to ensure the command line tools are set for the version of Xcode you're attempting to build from.

Navigate to "Locations" in Xcode preferences (select Xcode from the menu bar, then "Preferences..." then "Locations"). In the drop down next to "Command Line Tools:" select the version of Xcode you're using and then attempt a build.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I have 4 versions of Xcode on my mac, and none of them are named simply 'Xcode'.  So, I changed the desired version name from `Xcode8.1` back to `Xcode`.

This part might not apply to most people: If you're using the `xcode-select` tool (you should if you have multiple versions of xcode on your computer) then you need to make sure `xcode-select` is pointing to the correct version with the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for using Xcode beta version

I assume this is due to archive in Xcode beta and the path location does not match. Of course, I experienced this and it worked. Just do this step:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/
```

And do upload to Fabric again.