# Installing Python3 on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Python3 on a Mac OS X Yosemite, and did that by running the following command:

```
$ brew install python3
```

When I tried that, I got the following error:

```
clang: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH
otool: error: unable to find utility "otool", not a developer tool or in PATH
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: That means you does not have ``clang`` and ``otool`` to build python source code. Have you had xcode Command Line Tools installed?

Comment: @kxxoling I have Xcode as a whole installed, is that fine?

Comment: I'm not sure whether Xcode CLI would be installed in this case.  When you are not sure, just reinstall it again.

Comment: I wonder when Apple will update the default install... maybe in a couple years, in 2020 when it is completely unsupported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `brew update` and then `brew doctor` first. The doctor diagnoses common issues.

Seems something's wrong with your Xcode/Command Line Tools. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30902106/4154977) answer might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using the [anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install) distribution, in particular [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

For OSX Yosemite, this is a link to the [Python 3.4 64-bit installer](https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh).

After downloading the application, open a terminal window, navigate to where you downloaded the app (e.g. cd ~/Downloads) and type:

```
bash Miniconda-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

Now close and re-open your terminal window for the changes to take effect.

To test your installation, enter the command `conda list` from the terminal. If installed correctly, you will see a list of packages that were installed.

From here, you should be able to follow the on-screen instructions.  If you get lost, you can refer to their [installation guide](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html#os-x-miniconda-install).

After installing conda, you need to create an environment. To install an new environment named `py3` with Python 3:

```
conda create --name py3 python=3
```

To activate this environment:

```
source activate py3
```

Here, I normally install iPython, iPython notebook and pyqt:

```
conda install ipython, ipython-notebook, pyqt
```

Now, to activate an ipython shell from within your environment:

```
ipython qtconsole
```

Although this reply does not attempt fix the homebrew issue, it answers the question of how to install Python3 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed the instructions, but, when I type $ python --version, I get: python: posix_spawn: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `python3 --version`.  You can also check the location of the binary with `which python` or `which python3`.  I've expanded my reply above.  Note that you generally work in python from the environment you create.  This is to prevent inadvertently damaging your system installation.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and 
[Try]: brew update 
[or Homebrew Install]: /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
(code source found at https://brew.sh/) 
Make sure processes finish, and then [Re-Try]: brew install python3

Answer (score 0):

For me, I ran `brew doctor` which said

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  pandoc
  heroku
  numpy
  unbound
  python@3.8
```

So I ran `brew link python@3.8`

And immediately after, `python3` suddenly works!