# Xcode 8 Command Line Tools Missing (Git, Clang, etc)

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos

Two days ago, I upgraded to OSX Sierra. My development tools seemed to be working fine after that.

However, today I upgraded Xcode 7.3.1 -> 8.1 to make certain features work for React-Native development. To be precise, I deleted the 7.3.1 and installed 8.1 anew. That is where the woes had started.

In particular, it seems that most of the Command Line Tools are gone. I get errors when trying to use `git` as well as other commands. I was able to get Git back after installing from .dmg file.

I have also tried installing Command Line Tools using `xcode-select --install` to no avail. Installation proceeds, but none of the tools become available afterwards.

As an example of what is happening, the following are the errors I receive when running: `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

```
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk" cannot be located.
gcc: error: unable to find utility "gcc", not a developer tool or in PATH
configure: error: clang version 3.0 or later is required
```

Does someone know what the issue might be and how one goes about getting the development environment set up on Sierra + Xcode 8.1?

Comment: did you get any solution to this?

Comment: Yes. I forget exactly what i did but i recall it involving several reinstalls of the XCode and manually adding some packages.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just need to restart my machine for it to work after spending hours debugging it.

Comment: For the future, I have found that Github repositories of the projects in question are a better place to get quicker help for cutting edge bugs when they occur. Good luck, mate!

Comment: I found this solution resolved the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30902106/2486302

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred after installing the new version of Xcode.

Just restarting helped for me. Sometimes, even quitting and restarting Terminal might also help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to repoint the command line tools to the new copy of Xcode. You can use `xcode-select` to do that, but the easiest way is, in Xcode, go to Preferences > Locations and choose the correct Xcode for the Command Line Tools pop-up menu at the bottom.

Also pls note that in order to use `xcode-select` you need to use `sudo`.