# RStudio error: unable to find utility "package", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: r, macos, package, rstudio

**Issue description:**

I'm trying to install 'ggplot2' package on my R studio I'm installing on MacOs Mojave 10.14.1. Each time I'm trying to installing using either

- `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = T)`
- R Studio -> tools -> install packages... and type down '`ggplot2`'

I have the following error appear:

```
sh: line 1:  1549 Abort trap: 6      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
error: unable to find utility "package_name", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

**My approach to solve the issue:**

- I made sure that Xcode installed and updated
- in R Studio, I made sure that I'm able to download contents without using secure HTTPS method 
  tools -> global options -> packages -> unchecked 'Use secure download method for HTTP '

none of above approaches worked for me.

How can I overcome this issue ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come across the solution in Stackoverflow provided by [Ivan Mir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30902106/8477836), basically you need do the following:

Check out `xcode-select --print-path` in your Terminal.

If it's `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` then run

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools to set xcode-select to non-Xcode Command Line Tools`.

In case you don't have /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools directory, you can get them [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) for your current Xcode version.