# Fabric Archive packaging Error -6

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

When I package from XCode via Fabric Plugin a Beta in debug mode, I got an error :

**Fabric Archive packaging Error -6**

In Xcode I have check code signing manual (or auto same problem) for the app and the widget/extension with valid certificates and provisionning.

I also check that I have all certificates (public/private keys) and provisionning on my keychain.

If I build with fastlane last version 2.58.0, I got the same issue than direcly build from XCode.

Note that without any changes, one day it's work, an other that fails. This is strange.

Any help?

Comment: If you build and try the distribution to Beta with fastlane, what error do you see in the output?

Comment: The error is archive packaging error -6 with a provisionning sha1 but this one does not exist on the folder where Xcode save all of them.

Comment: If you use `sigh`(https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/sigh/) to generate a new profile, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, i have the same error : with fastlane i use with sigh(development:true,
     provisioning_name:provisioning_name)
   
  # provisioning_name is a Debug registered one
  gym(scheme: scheme,
       export_method: "development", 
        configuration: "Debug",
        xcargs: xcargs,
        clean: true,
        include_bitcode: false)

Comment: Archive Packaging Error: -6 Error re-signing the application for distribution

I finally manage to upload a debug archive into Fabric (plugin) via XCode (not fastlane) by manually set an 'iPhone Distribution' certificate in 'xcode/build settings/code signing identity/debug' as well as an adhoc provisioning profile in 'xcode/build settings/Provisioning profile/debug' instead of the 'iPhone developper certificate' and 'Debug provisionning profile' ones (both on app, widget and rich push extensions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fabric Plugin: Archive Packaging Error: -6 Error re-signing the application for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947348/fabric-plugin-archive-packaging-error-6-error-re-signing-the-application-for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if you have the certificates and profiles on your keychain, you may need to refresh them. To do this in Xcode 9, follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686725/6543020

Possible duplicate of: [Fabric Plugin: Archive Packaging Error: -6 Error re-signing the application for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947348/fabric-plugin-archive-packaging-error-6-error-re-signing-the-application-for)

Comment: Agree, make sure provisioning file match with signing